# Fence touching soil and bark

Tags: fence, moisture, soil

Fence built by a builder. Coming up on one year warranty. Was thinking about long term implications for a fence that is buried at least 3 inches in between soil and bark. Unless this is not to fence building code I doubt builder will do anything about it. I suspect it’s treated wood at least but not sure if I ought to do something more to protect the integrity of the fence long term?

[image]

Comment: What are the fence boards made of? Cedar? Redwood? Pine? Two of those will be fine, one will only be fine if it is pressure treated--it's hard to tell because this has been painted. There is no "fence building code", only local municipal codes that state max heights and max let-in distances for fences depending on where in your property they are placed.

Comment: They are cedar boards, stained and pressure treated according to the builder.

Comment: Cedar is never pressure treated because it naturally repels rot and insects that cause damage. It could well be 'cedar tone' pine which is pressure treated pine given a surface coat of some paint/stain or combination stain/stealer to make it look like cedar.

Comment: Apologies. The posts are pressure treated. The boards are cedar and stained.

Answer (score 2):

Even if the fence is treated, it will not last. The treatment is light, not meant to be buried.  I had to fix exactly this problem on my rental property.

1. Clear the bark away from the front and under the fence.
2. Use a plastic lawn edging and staple it against the bottom edge of the fence.

This assumes that the other side of the fence is not burried.

[image]